# Dump Session Into SQL Database

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Is it possible to dump a ColdFusion session into a SQL database? I have many session values and what I want is to just dump all of them into a database. I didn't know if I had to write each value to the database or If I could just have a huge session that just dumps all values or variables that were used into a database.. Basically what I have is a checkout form, they fill out many questions and then confirm on the last page. When they hit confirm I want everything they've entered in the entire session to dump into a database. Does anyone know where I can find an example of this or can provide one?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "dump a session" and what you are ultimately trying to achieve? It is certainly possible to export the "values" in the session scope to json, xml, ecetera. Then store that string in a database. But without knowing more about your end goal, I am not sure if that is what you are asking.

Comment: If you have simple session variables (no objects), then serialize the session struct to XML and save that.

Comment: Dynamic names will not make a difference. Like Adrian said, as long as they are simple values (string, number, date,..) you can just serialize the structure to xml (json, etcetera) and save it to the db. Though I am curious what you are going to do with all that data once it is there ...

Comment: @David: comments are only meant to be temporary. Please [edit] this information into your question.

Comment: *I didn't know if I had to write each value to the database* All depends on what you ultimately need to do with the information  (which you never mentioned). If this is just for debugging that is one thing. However if you plan to do anything with this information later on - like run queries, generate reports, etcetera - you should be storing the data differently. Create proper tables for the various entities. Store the values individually in the appropriate columns and rows - rather than "glom" everything together and store it in a single field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do exactly what you say you want, do something like this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="sessiondata">
<cfdump var="#session#" format="text">
</cfsavecontent>

<cfquery>
insert into table 
(sessiondata)
values
(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value=#SessionData#">)
```

It's quick and simple and leaves you with data that's difficult to do anything with.  If it was me, I'd do something like this:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop collection="#session#" item="x">
key is #x# value is #session[x]# <br />
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Except, instead of displaying the key value pairs, I'd store them in a normalized manner in a relational database.

Comment: SerializeJSON(Session) would also give you a string you could just throw in the DB and deserialze as needed. It might provide more flexibility.

Comment: Is "confirm" a submit control of an html form?

Comment: Then put the code in the page to which that form submits.

Comment: *quick and simple and leaves you with data that's difficult to do anything with* ... Which means if you intend to do anything more than dumping it to the screen for debugging, you will want to use a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use objectSave() to get something comprehensive if your session has any complexity. This way you can store objects that you might have in your session. While it is still limited a tiny bit, it's the most flexible of any solution. . Here is an example:

```
<cfscript>

// add an object to your session
session.fun_obj = createObject( "java", "java.util.Random").init();

// convert session to binary
sessionEncoded = charsetEncode( objectSave( session ), "iso-8859-1" );

// fake inserting data into a query / reading from query
qry = queryNew( 'id,session_object', 'varchar,varchar', {id : 1, session_object : sessionEncoded } );

// clear the session to prove it works
structClear( session );
writeDump( session, "browser", "html", false, "Your empty Session:" );

// try to use an object in the session, it will fail
try{
    writeOutput( session.fun_obj.nextInt() );
}
catch(any e){
    writeOutput("Failed, method not found<br>");
}

// read out session from db, and append to our session
structAppend( session, objectLoad(  charsetDecode( qry.session_object[1], "iso-8859-1" ) ) , true );

// show that we have our object back in session key
writeOutput( "Here is your random int: " & session.fun_obj.nextInt() & "<br>" );

// show off the session
writeDump( session, "browser", "html", true, "Your Session:" );
</cfscript>
```

There is one caveat, if you try to store something using objectSave() that it can't understand, it will not throw a bug, it will just ignore it. For instance, session.myfunction = function(){writeOutput('hello')}; would not serialize, but it would also not throw an error.

Reference: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ObjectSave

Comment: @DavidBrierton - This is another good alternative to json/xml for saving complex objects. However, I would still ask *what* you will ultimately be doing with the saved data. As mentioned in the comments, if you eventually need to query the detailed data (edit, generate reports, etc..), then saving everything in one big blob is almost certainly the wrong approach.